# How to dynamically group and display groups on a visualisation axis dependent on slicer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, finance

I have [reporting quarter] data e.g. 2023-Q1, 2022-Q4, ... etc. each quarter of data has information on result movements and absolute values on different financial years [fin_yr], for example 2023-Q1 may give values on financial years (2024 - 2002). I am using a slicer to select which quarter's information to display, and have it to be single select only.

Is there a way I can create groupings dynamically for the financial years for each reporting quarter?

For example, if 2023-Q1 was selected I may want to show 2024 - 2009 individually and then group 2008 and prior into a single value. I want to use these groupings for axes in charts, to avoid showing too many years at once.

I can see this can be done manually in the visualisations panel for the fields in each visual, but is there a way this can be done to dynamically change for each selected quarter?